# Angular2 route including id

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In an Angular2 project, I struggle to make the router works properly.

In our app, we only have the main page and then a project dedicated pages.
 For example, the user access these project pages using a direct link pointing to

```
http:/ourwebsite.com/#/project/b288ba45-3b41-4862-9fed-7271245b9c29
```

I want, in the header navbar, to create a link pointing to the given component even if the user goes to home after that.

For example: the user goes to his project, then click `Home`, I want the link `See project` being able to redirect the user to his previous precise project.

`My Routes`:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'project/:uuid',  component: ProjectComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent  }
];
```

My `app.component.html` with nav header:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/project', uuid]">See a project</a></li
</ul>
```

I tried this in `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  uuid: string;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.uuid = params['uuid'];
       console.log('Route UUID', this.uuid);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

But the fact is the `UUID` is printed in console as Undefined as this route is directly accessed from an external link.

I can get the `UUID` from the `project.component.ts` but how to pass it to the **routerLink** element in my navbar, which is located in `app.component`?

> Use of comment solution:

I tried to use `[routerLink]="['/project', {uuid: uuid}]"` but the produced link url is: /#/think;uuid=undefined

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to pass an  object mapping parameter names to parameter values. `[routerLink]="['/project', {uuid: uuid}]"`

Comment: I tried your solution and the produced link url is: /#/think;uuid=undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only one link saved at a time, you could save `uuid` as a *global variable* and then use it when generating a link.

You can add a global variable this way:

1) Create a new *service* (let's call it "SharedService") where you keep your *global variable* (you should also assign a value to it there, so that it would be initialized). You can also keep more global variables there.

`shared.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  public uuid: string = '';

  constructor() { }

}
```

2) Import *SharedService* to your `app.ts` or `app.module.ts` (however it is called in your filesystem) and add it to providers in the same `app.ts` or `app.module.ts` file:

```
providers: [SharedService]
```

DON'T add *SharedService* to *providers* in any other components, because it will be initialized again and you'll end up with several instances of your global variable when you only want to have only one of them.

3) Now import *SharedService* to all the components you want to use your global variable in and also add that *service* to the constructor of each of those components:

`set.component.ts`:

```
 constructor(private shared: SharedService) {
    this.shared.uuid = 'test';
 }
```

`get.component.ts`:

```
 constructor(private shared: SharedService) {
    console.log(this.shared.uuid);
 }
```

Comment: How and especially where in angular2 can I define a globally scoped variable?

Comment: I edited my answer and added a full example, I hope it helps and I didn't miss anything.